# Chrome Extensions storage.local.set "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Chrome's local storage for a browser extensions. When attempting to store an object, I randomly get an error sometimes of "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined", breaking at the line where I call chrome.storage.local.set() like so:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"channels":ContentApp.channels}, function(data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

The error never happens the first time I store the object, only after that initial storage. Anyone know what's causing this? I don't see a property 'name' being accessed on that line, or in any of the functions in the stack trace, so I don't get where the 'name' property is coming from.

Comment: What does ContentApp.channels equal if you inspect it at the breakpoint?

Comment: Also, what happens if you try running the command from the console itself multiple times?

Comment: ContentApp.channels is a object with a bunch of properties, I can inspect it in the debugger and it's fine. if I spam the command in the console a bunch of times it doesn't throw any error

Comment: ah I figured it out. the error was actually coming from a method that was being called within the chrome.storage.local.set() callback. the stacktrace wasn't bubbling out of the callback so it just said the error was being thrown by the .set() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, but I'm posting it so anyone who faces the same confusion sees this.

The error was being thrown at the line of

```
chrome.storage.local.set()
```

but in reality it was happening inside a method that was being called within the callback. The call stack of the error didn't bubble out of the callback of .set(), so it was reported at the line of the .set() call.